# How to use the Laplace distribution in a GLM model

Tags: r, glm

Good morning everyone! I am a PhD student and I am performing some statistical analysis on a behavioral dataset related to aggression of pied flycatchers males against other male intruders. The aggression variables I am using are "males peck rate" (M_PECKS_H) and "males attack rate" (M_ATTACKS_H) and both have a Poisson distribution (I have tried transforming them to reach normality, but with no result). The research question I want to answer is: does the male's aggression depend on his ornamental traits? To answer this question, using the R software, I tried running GLM models with the aggression variable as the dependent variable, and the variables describing the male's ornaments as the independent variables (I performed a model for each aggression variable, so a total of two models). Performing some preliminary analysis, I realized that the two aggression variables (males peck rate and males attack rate) are highly correlated (B = 0.257, p<0.001), so it was suggested that I calculate the residuals of one variable for the other, and enter the residuals into the model as the dependent variable (I named the residual variable as "males physical aggression"). The problem is that this new variable is not normally distributed (I tried transforming it with common transformation methods, but to no avail). I used Statgraphics 19 software to figure out the closest distribution to its real distribution, and the result was "Laplace distribution." So my final question is, how can I perform a GLM model having a variable with a Laplace distribution as the dependent variable? If not, could there be another solution?

I also add the three variables involved, if they can help with an answer Thank you in advance to everyone who will answer me!

````
 [1]  0.32763821 -0.94806221  0.42966113 -0.40705296  1.64623753 -0.40606605 -1.69628970
 [8] -0.18288893 -0.24489983 -0.44856501 -0.36268715 -0.38924716  0.20351015 -0.40340094
[15] -0.24993494 -0.44856501 -0.13957284 -0.04492754 -0.44856501 -0.44856501  1.03867845
[22] -0.22239376  0.21517449 -0.29628075  0.35389341 -0.41711847  0.08461163 -0.09946749
[29] -0.44856501 -0.26643190 -0.44856501 -0.59306794 -0.07874262  0.65301432 -0.06027983
[36]  0.17872541  0.45812268  1.79260136 -0.38160072 -0.42591568  0.44959796 -0.22706765
[43]  0.23904110 -0.47172246 -0.33855633 -0.53399640  0.17416460  0.13808756 -0.38823318
[50] -0.08711228  1.30076077 -0.44856501 -0.44856501 -0.05768553  2.01970970  0.16219602
[57] -0.25543196 -0.16661012  0.52462825  2.55114656 -0.38777473  0.27825875 -0.10859473
[64] -0.29182520```

``` M_ATTACKS_H
 [1] 1.04992280 0.72911392 1.27087576 0.05741627 3.12781955 0.09528851 4.18945312 0.29543420
 [9] 0.22116904 0.00000000 0.08587786 0.05931785 1.03394256 0.06246746 0.22338049 0.00000000
[17] 0.37368626 0.60900265 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.71682289 0.22617124 0.81407035 0.15228426
[25] 0.99122354 0.03144654 0.92912448 0.50713154 0.00000000 0.21638331 0.00000000 1.33806386
[33] 0.38772213 1.22320962 1.30573248 0.64516129 1.46143437 3.13621964 0.06696429 0.05078290
[41] 3.81947744 0.23797719 0.68760611 0.06015038 0.15215554 0.79107505 1.72962227 1.90779014
[49] 0.06033182 0.37894737 2.86294416 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.39087948 3.21804511 0.61076103
[57] 0.19313305 0.28195489 1.34604599 4.05882353 0.06079027 0.95642933 0.38980510 0.15673981```

```M_PECKS_H
 [1] 0.49408132 2.21772152 0.70875764 0.02870813 1.86466165 0.09528851 9.81445312 0.05371531
 [9] 0.03159558 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.68929504 0.03123373 0.04467610 0.00000000
[17] 0.11677696 0.37069726 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.41440552 0.00000000 0.27135678 0.00000000
[25] 0.34073309 0.00000000 0.71471114 0.28526149 0.00000000 0.06182380 0.00000000 2.67612772
[33] 0.03231018 0.21955044 1.65605095 0.03225807 1.00135318 1.61562830 0.00000000 0.05078290
[41] 5.27315915 0.02974715 0.00000000 0.15037594 0.07607777 1.58215010 1.99801193 2.38473768
[49] 0.00000000 0.03157895 2.01015228 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.00000000 1.35338346 0.00000000
[57] 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.67302299 1.91176471 0.00000000 0.41445271 0.08995502 0.00000000```
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Do you wish to use R for this? If so, please add it as a tag in the question. :)